# How to deploy OpenBSD on NanoPi R1?

Tags: openbsd, nanopi

I have a task to deploy **OpenBSD** on the **NanoPI R1** microcomputer, which has an Allwinner H3 processor  **armv7** architecture family. The official documentation does not say anything about the support of this board. But there are similar ones. For one, **OrangePI Zero**.

*In second photo i will show which boards are supported.*

[Boards are supported by OpenBSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCFPv.png)

But if you look at their images and **armv7** images, then there’s a completely different picture:

[FTP server screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDwke.png)

There are only 5 computers and no one using **Allwinner H3**
Of course, I decided to use the right scientific approach and I tried to deploy each image on the board.
Firstly I used **Etcher** (*on Windows*) later as written in the documentation (by the way it is terrible in my opinion) I used **dd** command. But nothing happened.

Surfing the Internet, I came across an article that described the installation  [**OpenBSD on NanoPI Neo**](https://www.cambus.net/openbsd-arm64-on-the-nanopi-neo2/).
But the author did not disclose in my opinion how he did it all. I got confused even more.

I also tried to find the old version where there is an image for **Orange PI Zero** (was built on the **Allwinner** processor). But its were not on the server, even in older versions. I will be grateful to everyone who will help me decide or go to the decision.